# Apache Spark write to multiple outputs [different parquet schemas] without caching

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to transform my input data (XML files) and produce 3 different outputs.

Each output will be in parquet format and will have a different schema/number of columns.

Currently in my solution, the data is stored in `RDD[Row]`, where each Row belongs to one of three types and has a different number of fields. What I'm doing now is caching the RDD, then filtering it (using the field telling me about the record type) and saving the data using the following method:

```
var resultDF_1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered_data_1, schema_1)
resultDF_1.write.parquet(output_path_1)
...
// the same for filtered_data_2 and filtered_data_3
```

**Is there any way to do it better, for example do not cache entire data in memory?**

In MapReduce we have MultipleOutputs class and we can do it this way:

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "data_type_1", DataType1OutputFormat.class, Void.class, Group.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "data_type_2", DataType2OutputFormat.class, Void.class, Group.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "data_type_3", DataType3OutputFormat.class, Void.class, Group.class);
...
MultipleOutputs<Void, Group> mos = new MultipleOutputs<>(context);
mos.write("data_type_1", null, myRecordGroup1, filePath1);
mos.write("data_type_2", null, myRecordGroup2, filePath2);
...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem... You do not want to load the whole dataset? Are you stuck with RDD or can you use dataframes (performance should be better - if this is your issue)?

Comment: Yes, I want to load whole dataset. My current problem is data caching. I have a lot of input data to process. In my current solution, I have to split one RDD into 3 separate RDDs that have a different schema. I use filter function so at the beginning I cache entire RDD. The general outline of the problem is: how to process data and save to different parquet files with different schem. Example: 1 input XML message consists of Request and Response part. You want to transform it to parquet and produce two output datasets: one for RQ and the other for RS

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly this problem, to re-iterate: we read 1000s of datasets into one RDD, all of different schemas (we used a nested `Map[String, Any]`) and wanted to write those 1000s of datasets to different Parquet partitions in their respective schemas.  All in a single embarrassingly parallel Spark Stage.

Our initial approach indeed did the hacky thing of caching, but this meant (a) 1000 passes of the cached data (b) hitting a lot of memory issues!

For a long time now I've wanted to bypass the Spark's provided `.parquet` methods and go to lower level underlying libraries, and wrap that in a nice functional signature.  Finally recently we did exactly this!

The code is too much to copy and paste all of it here, so I will just paste the main crux of the code to explain how it works.  We intend on making this code Open Source in the next year or two.

```
      val successFiles: List[String] = successFilePaths(tableKeyToSchema, tableKeyToOutputKey, tableKeyToOutputKeyNprs)

      // MUST happen first
      info("Deleting success files")
      successFiles.foreach(S3Utils.deleteObject(bucket, _))

      if (saveMode == SaveMode.Overwrite) {
        info("Deleting past files as in Overwrite mode")
        parDeleteDirContents(bucket, allDirectories(tableKeyToOutputKey, tableKeyToOutputKeyNprs, partitions, continuallyRunStartTime))
      } else {
        info("Not deleting past files as in Append mode")
      }

      rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
        case (index, records) =>
          records.toList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).foreach {
            case (regularKey: RegularKey, data: List[NotProcessableRecord Either UntypedStruct]) =>
              val (nprs: List[NotProcessableRecord], successes: List[UntypedStruct]) =
                Foldable[List].partitionEither(data)(identity)

              val filename = s"part-by-partition-index-$index.snappy.parquet"

              Parquet.writeUntypedStruct(
                data = successes,
                schema = toMessageType(tableKeyToSchema(regularKey.tableKey)),
                fsMode = fs,
                path = s3 / bucket / tableKeyToOutputKey(regularKey.tableKey) / regularKey.partition.pathSuffix /?
                  continuallyRunStartTime.map(hourMinutePathSuffix) / filename
              )

              Parquet.writeNPRs(
                nprs = nprs,
                fsMode = fs,
                path = s3 / bucket / tableKeyToOutputKeyNprs(regularKey.tableKey) / regularKey.partition.pathSuffix /?
                  continuallyRunStartTime.map(hourMinutePathSuffix) / filename
              )
          } pipe Iterator.single
      }.count() // Just some action to force execution

      info("Writing _SUCCESS files")
      successFiles.foreach(S3Utils.uploadFileContent(bucket, "", _))
```

Of course this code cannot be copy and pasted as many methods and values are not provided.  The key points are:

1. We hand crank the deleting of `_SUCCESS` files and previous files when overwriting
2. Each spark partition will result in one-or-many output files (many when multiple data schemas are in the same partition)
3. We hand crank the writing of `_SUCCESS` files

Notes:

- `UntypedStruct` is our nested representation of arbitrary schema.  It's a little bit like `Row` in Spark but much better, as it's based on `Map[String, Any]`.
- `NotProcessableRecord` are essentially just dead letters

`Parquet.writeUntypedStruct` is the crux of the logic of writing a parquet file, so we'll explain this in more detail.  Firstly

```
val toMessageType: StructType => MessageType = new org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SparkToParquetSchemaConverter().convert
```

Should be self explanatory.  Next `fsMode` contains within it the `com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials`, then inside `writeUntypedStruct` we use that to construct `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` setting `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key`.

`writeUntypedStruct` basically just calls out to:

```
  def writeRaw(
    data: List[UntypedStruct],
    schema: MessageType,
    config: Configuration,
    path: Path,
    compression: CompressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY
  ): Unit =
    Using.resource(
      ExampleParquetWriter.builder(path)
        .withType(schema)
        .withConf(config)
        .withCompressionCodec(compression)
        .withValidation(true)
        .build()
    )(writer => data.foreach(data => writer.write(transpose(data, new SimpleGroup(schema)))))
```

where `SimpleGroup` comes from `org.apache.parquet.example.data.simple`, and `ExampleParquetWriter extends ParquetWriter<Group>`.  The method `transpose` is a very tedious self writing recursion through the `UntypedStruct` populating a `Group` (some ugly Java mutable low level thing).

Credit must go to https://github.com/davidainslie for figuring out how these underlying libraries work, and labouring out the code, which like I said, we intend on making Open Source soon!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to split one RDD into multiple RDD per se. This is just how the way Spark's DAG works: only child RDDs pulling data from parent RDDs.

We can, however, have multiple child RDDs reading from the same parent RDD. To avoid recomputing the parent RDD, there is no other way but to cache it. **I assume that you want to avoid caching because you're afraid of insufficient memory.** We can avoid Out Of Memory (OOM) issue by persisting the RDD to `MEMORY_AND_DISK` so that large RDD will spill to disk if and when needed.

Let's begin with your original data:

```
val allDataRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(Row(1,1,1),Row(2,2,2),Row(3,3,3)))
```

We can persist this in memory first, but allow it to spill over to disk in case of insufficient memory:

```
allDataRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

We then create the 3 RDD outputs:

```
filtered_data_1 = allDataRDD.filter(_.get(1)==1) // //
filtered_data_2 = allDataRDD.filter(_.get(2)==1) // use your own filter funcs here
filtered_data_3 = allDataRDD.filter(_.get(3)==1) // //
```

We then write the outputs:

```
var resultDF_1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered_data_1, schema_1)
resultDF_1.write.parquet(output_path_1)
var resultDF_2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered_data_2, schema_2)
resultDF_2.write.parquet(output_path_2)
var resultDF_3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filtered_data_3, schema_3)
resultDF_3.write.parquet(output_path_3)
```

---

If you truly really want to avoid multiple passes, there is a workaround using a custom partitioner. You can repartition your data into 3 partitions and each partition will have its own task and hence its own output file/part. The caveat is that parallelism will be heavily reduced to 3 threads/tasks, and there's also the risk of >2GB of data stored in a single partition (Spark has a 2GB limit per partition). I am not providing detailed code for this method because I don't think it can write parquet files with different schema.

Comment: Thanks @LeightonRitchie for your feedback. Yes, I want to avoid caching due to unnecessary waste of resources (memory and possibly disk). We are currently moving our old project, which is written as a MapReduce job. In MR approach we use `MultipleOutputs` and the data is not cached anywhere. We are looking for how to achieve something similar in Spark.

Comment: Spark supports all Hadoop output formats when you use RDD level abstractions but at Dataset level, write logic is abstracted. Maybe using RDD would work. It would require writing logic for writing in parquet format as well.